# Get Total Subtotal for products in 1 specific category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to use this code to get the subtotal for a specific category shoes and replace the default subtotal as i don't want to include subtotals from products in other categories.

```
function cat_cart_subtotal() {
    
$terms = array('shoes'); 

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        
    $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        
    $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    
    if ( has_term( $terms, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
        
    $price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); 
        
    }
  
    return $price;
    
}
```

As seen in the following image, the cart total is $114.99 however i only want to display $39.99 as it applies to the shoes category only. The other product at $75 is NOT in the shoes category so i want it deducted from the cart total.

[image]

This code doesn't add the subtotals from multiple products from the same category as seen in the following image. How do i do that?

[image]